# DispatcherTimer.Start()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

```
public void DispatcherTimerSetup(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    Client = httpClient;
    dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0); // TimeSpan for 1 Minute 0 secs
    if (!dispatcherTimer.IsEnabled)
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }
}

class DispatcherTimer
{
    public void Start();
}
```

I am getting Error like this

DispatcherTimer.Start()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Comment: Why are you declaring your own DispatcherTimer class? You should use the [existing one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer). The error message is telling you that you need to provide an implementation for the `Start()` method because it is not an abstract method

Comment: Fisrt I declared this class like this DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;, After that I got this error DispatcherTimer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) for that I created Dispatcher Where i need to get this existing Dispatcher class. can you please help me I am new to MVC right now am using MVC4. thanks in advance

Comment: @user3065401 Now guess what that error message means?

Comment: @user3065401 If you are using MVC, you need to start by learning C#. MVC development requires a basic knowledge of how C# works as a language. There are also certain components which cannot be used effectively within an MVC project. DispatcherTimer is one of them. I suggest getting two decent books: One on C#/Visual Studio Development and one on MVC 4.0. Then, you will be able to ask questions here which are more likely to attract informative answers

Comment: Now I can able to do it please don't say Impossible people will get disappointment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have not imported the respective [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (`System.Windows.Threading`). You then created a class `DispatchTimer` which is not complete. Your implementation is missing the method body for the `Start()` method.

Add the namespace (`using System.Windows.Threading;`) that contains the built-in `DispatchTimer` class and remove your own implementation of the class and you should be fine.

Comment: After adding using System.Windows.Threading; this NM I got this error The type or namespace name 'Threading' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' So I think we need to add any assembly like WindowsBase.dll. or something else

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you're trying to do.

```
class DispatcherTimer
{
    public void Start();//<--Here is the problem method has nobody. Either you should add body or mark it abstract.
}
```

You should rename your class from `DispatcherTimer` to something else, am not sure how `Tick`, `Interval`, IsEnabled` doesn't gives error.

You should probably remove your `DispatcherTimer` class completely and use  `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`.

Am not sure whether you can use [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in Asp.Net, you may need to investigate.

Comment: Yes we need to Add this reference WindowsBase.dll  I got it Thanks to Alll...............

Answer (score 0):

You are *looking* for something like

```
public sealed class MyDispatcherTimer
{
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
    public void DispatcherTimerSetup(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        Client = httpClient;
        dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0); // TimeSpan for 1 Minute 0 secs

    }

    public void StartMyDispatcherTimer()
    {
        if (dispatcherTimer != null && !dispatcherTimer.IsEnabled)
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

But as some of the comments have said, why you are looking for this is not clear. There is already a `DispatcherTimer` class that works well so there should be no reason to wrap it.

I hope this helps.